# laravel check if amount is between two columns in the database

Tags: php, laravel

I have a weight calculated, and a database table that contains the range of amounts, now I want to check if the calculated weight is between the ranges in my table.

Shipping Fee Table

```
--------------------------------------------------
id  |  weight_from  |  weight_to   |   amount    |
----+---------------+--------------+--------------
 1  |      0.5      |      100     |     100     |
 2  |      500      |      1000    |     120     |
 3  |      1000     |      3000    |     180     |
```

For example the calculated weight is `505kg` it will find it on the table if it's between `weight_from` & `weight_to`

I found something like this, but it is not like what I'm trying to do, because it pass a number, and not getting the value of database table.

Code

```
$fee = Fee::whereBetween('column', [1, 150])->first();
```

Comment: you can use `>` and `<` with two `where` condition

Answer (score 1):

you can use `>` and `<` with two where condition

```
$fee = Fee::where('weight_from', '>=', 500)->where('weight_to', '<=', 500)->first();
```

Comment: sorry, Devsi, I realized. it's wrong, I want to check the amount if it's between in one of the records in the table.

Comment: @KonjeshEsbrading so which rows as result u want?