# laravel check amount if in between the records

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a weight calculated, and a database table that contains the range of amounts, now I want to check if the calculated weight is between the ranges in my table.

I want to check the amount if it's between in one of the records in the table.

For example the calculated weight is `505kg` it will find it on the table if it's between `weight_from` & `weight_to`, so it will return the `120 amount` because `505kg` is between `500 and 1000`

Shipping Fee Table

```
+-----+---------------+--------------+-------------+
| id  |  weight_from  |  weight_to   |   amount    |
+-----+---------------+--------------+-------------+
|  1  |      0.5      |      100     |     100     |
|  2  |      500      |      1000    |     120     |
|  3  |      1000     |      3000    |     180     |
+-----+---------------+--------------+-------------+
```

I found something like this, but it is not like what I'm trying to do, because it pass a number, and not getting the value of database table.

Code for reference only

```
$fee = Fee::whereBetween('column', [1, 150])->first();
```

Comment: Isn't this just the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64586967/laravel-check-if-amount-is-between-two-columns-in-the-database?

Answer (score 4):

`whereBetween()` is for finding values in a range within a single column. Since you are checking  between two different columns, the checks needs to be explicit.

```php
$weight = 505;
$fee = Fee::where('weight_from', '<=', $weight)
          ->where('weight_to', '>=', $weight)
          ->orderBy('weight_from')
          ->first();
if ($fee) {
    // Do something with $fee->amount;
}
```

You shouldn't use `<`, the ranges should be inclusive. The reason for this, contrary to the other answer that states "*use `>` for the upper-bound if the next range starts from the same value*", is that the range may not *always* have the same upper-limit as the start-limit of your next batch (for example, the sample data provided has a range from 0.5 to 100, but none from 100-500). If it doesn't, then suddenly you're missing a value. Its better to use `orderBy()` to find the correct record. Combine that with `first()` and you only get one record.

Comment: i think that's not what I'm trying to achieve because it's not searching the provided value in the database records, I will only check a single `amount` in the table for example `505`, so it will check if `505` is in between one of the records in the table.

Comment: Well, you need to substitute 1 and 150 to the value you are sending in.

Comment: I did, but it will limit the search to that value only because of the `>=` and `<=` it will not get the range of between `500` and `1000`

Comment: It will find where `weight_from` is greater or equal to the provided weight, AND the `weight_to` is less than or equal to the provided weight. So where the provided weight is between the ranges of from/to. If you're asking for something different, its quite unclear and you should clarify your question with explicit examples of desired input/output. From what I gather of the data in your question this achieves exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: actually, I realized it again that your answer/logic is wrong. it should be `weight_from`, '<=', $weight` and  `weight_from`, '>', $weight`

Comment: condition is not a typo

Comment: The order of conditions in my original answer, which I updated, was a typo... The upper limit should still be `<=`, in case there is no batch continuing from that exact upper limit.

Comment: Really after a 2 hours of  searching i found the answer

Answer (score -1):

I got it now, I want to share this simple yet helpful solution. This kind of logic is so confusing.

Code

```
$weight = 505;
$fee = Fee::where('weight_from', '<=', $weight)
          ->where('weight_to', '>', $weight)
          ->first();
if ($fee) {
    // Do something with $fee->amount;
}
```

The `weight_from` should be less (or equal) to the calculated weight, and `weight_to` should be greater than the calculated weight

Also, use `>` for the upper-bound if the next range starts from the same value.

Thanks to **tykus and MichalOravec** of Laracasts for helping me